# Dividing Up A Circular Search Area

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, circles, geometric-construction

**BACKSTORY**:  I need to collect 500 plant samples for strontium analysis.  The samples are randomly distributed across a circular area with a radius of 300 kilometers. I have to do this in 30 days, so I want to be methodical.

**REQUEST**: Divide the circle into 30 regions of equal area using lines and/or arcs, NONE OF WHICH pass through the  center of the circle. One wrinkle: I'd like each of the regions to have the highest compactness possible. That is, I'd like the average ratio of the area of the regions to the area of a circle having the same perimeter to be as close to 1:1 as possible.

**DESIRED RESULT**: An explanation of how to do this myself is good; a jpg of the solution is better!

Comment: Since the lines and arcs that divide the thirty regions cannot pass through the center of the circle, one region will contain that center in its interior.  I'd be inclined to make that region a circle (so its ratio of area to perimeter is just the same as a circle!).  That leaves twenty-nine regions to be created, possibly by making a couple of concentric rings of regions building out to fill the original circular area.

Comment: I would suggest 4 ranges around the middle: first with 2 half circle, second with 4 sections, third with 8, and fourth with 16. - total 30.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible, simple solution. The four circles have radii of $10\sqrt{30}$, $50\sqrt6$, $20\sqrt{105}$ and $300$ km. The first annulus is divided into 4 regions, the second one into 9 regions and the third one into 16. All regions have the same area.

[image]